# wireless AC card only shows up as wireless=IEEE 802.11abg

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

I have a **intel wireless 7260ac** card in my laptop which used to get 300Mb but now only gets 54Mb I see that it shows up as a IEEE 802.11abg after the resent ubuntu 16.04.1 upgrade how can I fix this?

I type the command 
**sudo lshw -C network**

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:4e:64:8e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: enp4s0f2
       version: 0a
       serial: 00:90:f5:f9:d9:f8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

I also did a check of my signal strength which is good using
**nmcli d wifi**

```
*  SSID                             MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
   guest_2.4ghz                Infra  7     54 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2     
*  2.4ghz                      Infra  7     54 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2     
   5ghz                        Infra  161   54 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```

I also did a **uname -a**

```
Linux sys76 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also did a **lsb_release -a**

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I did a iwconfig using **iwconfig wlp3s0**

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"2.4ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: E0:3F:49:93:3F:10   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:134   Missed beacon:0
```

I did a l**s /lib/firmware | grep 7260**

```
user1@sys76:~$ ls /lib/firmware | grep 7260
iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
```

Comment: Please post `dmesg | grep 7260` to [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the link here. For the syntax, pick "Bash Session".  And another for `iwlwifi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue I had the line 
`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`  added to my 
`/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file to which fixed another problem with disconnecting so I took this out and it fixed the speed problem. But I'm having to many problems with my wifi card and network-manager disconnecting and decided to try wicd.

Also added the line (to turn of wifi power management)

```
sleep 5 ; /sbin/iw wlp3s0 set power_save off
```

to my `/etc/rc.local file`

**Updated Answer:**

Updating this answer because ran into more problems and disconnects 
Here's a list of final changes that seem to be working.

```
1) Upgraded to to kernel 4.8.0-39 from 4.4 
2) Added files 
     -/etc/modprobe.d/iwldvm.conf
      added line: options iwldvm power_scheme=1

     -/etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf
      added line: options iwlmvm power_scheme=1

     -/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
      added line: options iwlwifi power_save=0
      added line: options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```